# Call Java Console Commands Within Code

Tags: java

That may sound stupid. But is it at all possible? I was thinking about creating a program that would allow someone to code inside it, and then run the code to test the output. To do this of course, I need to be able to compile and run Java from within Java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK6 added a [compiler tools api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well try to simulate the terminal or command line from a java program using the following code snippet ...

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","echo abc > test.txt"});
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","java HelloWorld > test.txt"});

    }
}
```

So what this code basically does is that it executes a bash shell in which it executes various shell commands like `echo abc > test.txt` (the first line in the main method) or `java HelloWorld > test.txt` (the second line in the main method). So here on, it is just like firing up shell commands but from a Java program